# Discord Bot с экономикой, как сделать разную базу данных json для разных серверов?

Tags: python, json, discord, бот, discord.py

Сделал Discord-бота с экономикой, в качестве базы данных использую привязанный к коду json файл. Друг увидел моего бота и захотел тоже его к себе на сервер. Но если кто-то на его сервере вводит команду shop (открывающую магазин с ролями) - открывается магазин с ролями моего сервера, которых у друга на его сервере нет. Также общий и счёт пользователей на обоих серверах (но против этого я ничего не имею против). **Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать персональный shop для каждого сервера.**

Answer (score 0):

У вас наверняка `json-файл` вашего сервера имеет какое-то название.

Вы можете создать для второго сервера другой файл с его данными и ролями, а затем **сделать для обоих файлов названия в формате `<id сервера>.json`**

Затем, при вызове команды `shop` из контекста получайте `id` сервера и открывайте соответствующий файл.

**Например:**

```
@bot.command()
async def shop(ctx):
    server_id = ctx.guild.id # получили id сервера
    json_file = open(f'{server_id}.json', 'r')
    data = json.loads(json_file.read())
    json_file.close()
```

В данном случае, в `data` будут считаны данные соответствующего сервера

Comment: Спасибо. А как сделать, чтобы баланс пользователей на обоих серверах был одинаковый?

Comment: Для баланса можно просто открывать файл какого-то одного сервера. Но правильнее в этом случае создать отдельный файл для всех серверов, что-то типа `balance.json`

Comment: А как сделать тогда команду buy (покупки роли)? Сделать так, чтобы он открывал сразу два json файла, с балансом и  со стоимостью роли (shop файл)?

Comment: У бота есть атрибут `guilds`. Вы можете в цикле для всех серверов открыть все файлы и для каждого из них провести необходимые действия. `for guild in bot.guilds: jsonfile = open(f'{guild.id}.json', 'r')`

Comment: А что делать если при команде удаления роли из магазина, у меня удаляется весь Json-файл, вот код: 
@bot.command()
async def removeshop(ctx,role:discord.Role):
    server_id = ctx.guild.id 
    with open(f'{server_id}.json', 'r') as f:
        shop = json.load(f)
    if not str(role.id) in shop['shop']:
        await ctx.send("Этой роли нет в магазине")
    if str(role.id) in shop['shop']:
        await ctx.send('Роль удалена из магазина')
        del shop['shop'][str(role.id)]
    with open(f'{server_id}.json', 'w') as f:
        shop = json.load(f)

Comment: @ProffessorPepsi, дополните вопрос этим кодом, а также структурой json-файла

Comment: Мне кажется json-файл очищается потому что когда вы открываете его на запись, вы ничего туда не записываете - `with open(f'{server_id}.json', 'w') as f: shop = json.load(f)`

Comment: Так with open(f'{server_id}.json', 'w') as f: shop = json.load(f)  - как раз и сохраняет все изменения, которые были произведены.

Comment: `json.load()` используется, чтобы считать json-строку, а не записать файл. Поэтому у вас файл очищается и ничего не сохраняет. Используйте [`json.dumps()`](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-json.html)

Comment: А всё понял, спасибо большое, теперь всё работает